# Javascript difference in seconds between two datetime cross browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, cross-browser

I have a function where i need to calculate the difference in seconds between two datetime.
I do something like this:

```
var sData = new Date(Date.parse(sData));
var tData = new Date(Date.parse(response.scroll.datain));
var timeDiff = Math.abs(tData.getTime() - sData.getTime());
timeDiff = parseInt(timeDiff)/1000;
```

Chrome return the correct difference in seconds between the two datetime fields, firefox and opera return 0.
How can achieve this result in cross browser mode?

Thanks in advance

Comment: best guess is format of date strings isn't valid. Provide sample data for the 2 date strings

Comment: Just pass miliseconds from controller and then create new Date(miliseconds)

Comment: Firefox and opera say that sData and tData are "invalid Data", chrome don't

Comment: @almal - What is `sData`? Is it a valid Date string? ([RFC2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14) or [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime))

Comment: is a data parameter from mysql db retrive by an ajax call.

Comment: chrome return by console.log Wed Oct 01 2014 14:09:11 GMT+0200 (CEST), firefox return Invalid Date why?? And if i use typeof all browser return Undefined

Comment: into the db the date is formatted YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

the issue is MYSQL date-time format.
A workaround could be this:

```
var t = response.scroll[i].datain.split(/[- :]/);
var s = sData.split(/[- :]/);

// Apply each element to the Date function
var tData = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
var sData = new Date(s[0], s[1]-1, s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]);
```

work for all major browser.